# Refused to connect to ‘http://localhost:5555/’ because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: “connect-src ‘self’ https:”

Tags: esb, webmethod, amazon-mws, webmethods, webmethods-caf

Issue I’m facing now is, one of our custom Portlet which trying to establish the connection from Portal to ESB server we’re getting error on the console as “Refused to connect to ‘http://localhost:5555/’ because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: “connect-src ‘self’ https:”.“

And the same war file when we promote it to higher environments, its working as expected and users were able to perform their day today activity.

Hence I’m unsure whether the issue is with the installation or Firewall related or do we need to explicitly configure any additional parameters to over come this error, because the Custom portlet is working as expected when we promote it to other environments.

Error messages:
I got this error from Console when I inspect the browser screen,
“Refused to connect to ‘http://localhost:5555/’ because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: “connect-src ‘self’ https:”

And nothing was printed in server logs or error logs.

To resolve this error Content Security Policy directive: “connect-src ‘self’ https:” and make the application establish the connection successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Under: Manage Response Header Rules
Update: include connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' http://localhost:*; font-src 'self' https:;